# Is there any benefit to write a driver node based on driver_base package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using a customized 2D laser range finder (not SICK/HOKUYO).
This laser range finder has its own protocol so I must write my own driver node to get the 2D scan and publish it in "sensor_msgs/LaserScan".

I'm wondering if I should write my own driver node based on "driver_base" package, like "hokuyo_node" package.
Is there any benefit to use the "driver_base" package?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215584/is-there-any-benefit-to-write-a-driver-node-based-on-driver_base-package/) by [Curtis Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/23462/curtis-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have never used it myself, but having a look at the [WikiPage](http://wiki.ros.org/driver_base), it does not seem to be a good idea to use it, as it is deprecated.

> A framework for writing drivers that
> helps with runtime reconfiguration,
> diagnostics and self-test. This
> package is deprecated.
>
> API Stability This package is for
> internal use only. Its API is stable,
> but not recommended for use by new
> packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0